# Simple template engine for user-edited files

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates

I am using nodeJS (server) and Dojo (client). I am writing a system that should allow users to create user-defined messages (they could be text-only email or SMS). I want to give a lot of flexibility. I would like to:

- Pass the users a number of variables
- Give the user a Web form
- Allow the user to cycle through the data in the variables, print it, etc
- The result of the script execution is a text file

This could even be used to allow them to create invoices. However, at this stage I am more focused on text.

I am thinking of allowing straight Javascript, and then eval() whatever they wrote in it. But... I am not sure.

What's the best practice solution for such a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use eval, read the following for why.

[Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

For JavaScript templating see the following list.

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-templating

Comment: Well the page starts with "DEPRECATED. This page is deprecated." right at the top. Any good ones you would suggest for what I need to do?

Comment: Checkout [EJS](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs) & [jade](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade)

Comment: I actually set my eyes on https://github.com/tbranyen/combyne.js which, amongst all of them, seems to be the be the most END-user-friendly -- and it's not tag-oriented but text-oriented...